# Grails, make an action be called repeatedly once a day, week etc

Tags: events, grails, time

I want to have an action o procedure called periodically once a day without the need of having someone logged in.

Is that possible and if it is: How can I do it?

This is my Trigger:

```
package com.myproj.jobs


class DailyCheck {
    static triggers = {
//        cron name: 'dailyCheck', cronExpression: "03 * * * * ?"
            simple name: 'myJobSimple', repeatInterval: 6000
    }


def dailyCheckService
def execute() {
    println(">>>>>>>>> DAILY JOB EXECUTES <<<<<<<")
    dailyCheckService.checkOffers()
}
```

}

Part of my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
compile "org.grails:grails-core"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.2.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.2.Final"
console "org.grails:grails-console"
compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.12'
profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.11.6"
runtime "com.h2database:h2"
testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
runtime 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1' 
compile "ca.redtoad:grails-phonenumbers:0.11"
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:3.0.0.M2'
compile 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.0'
compile 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.5.3'
compile 'org.grails.plugins:rendering:2.0.3'
runtime "org.springframework:spring-test:4.2.1.RELEASE"
compile "org.grails.plugins:excel-export:2.1"
```

}

Comment: There is a quartz plugin for whatever version of grails you are using

Comment: Fine I'll check that out. I'm using Grails-3.2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by adding a config file in grails-app/conf named QuartzConfig.groovy having the following content:

```
quartz {
  autoStartup = true
  jdbcStore = false
}
environments {
  test {
    quartz {
        autoStartup = false
    }
  }
}
```

And to Mike W I will add that there is still no logging visible at start so it might have been taken away with this latest version?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [quartz plugin](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/quartz) e.g.

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.12'
}
```

/grails-app/jobs/MyJob.groovy

```
class MyJob{
    static triggers = {
        // fire every day at 12:30
        cron name: 'myJobCron', cronExpression: "0 30 12 * * ?"
    }

    def myService

    def execute( context ) {
        myService.doStuff()
    }
}
```

Comment: Really that simple? I'll take a while until I get any results. Thank's!

Comment: Well, it seems that it never executes, as I'm testing I run in development mode and I understand that I need to configure the plugin but there is no config file to edit. I also tried "grails install-quartz-config" but grails doesn't find this command.

Comment: You don't need to add config unless you want fine grained control over certain aspects, what did you change your cron schedule to? You can use a simple trigger instead e.g. this which will fire every 60 seconds `simple name: 'myJobSimple', repeatInterval: 6000000`, add it to the triggers block & comment out the cron schedule

Comment: I included my code in the question. Tried the simple but nothing happens.

Comment: If installed correctly you should see a block of logging when app boots related to quartz, it'll contain something like `QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.2 created` are you seeing this?

Comment: No, nothing about quartz is printed at boot. You can see my build.gradle, the part of dependencies, in my question.

Comment: Try changing the quartz plugin version to 2.0.9 `compile "org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.9"`

Comment: No, this didn't help. I Tried with a test-project using grails-3.3.0 but none of the quartz-versions worked. I can see that the quartz modules compile at the first run but then nothing more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155591/discussion-between-mike-w-and-larand).